# concept in header doesn't constrain a parameter pack in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Context: I am rewriting a library that worked with the GCC -fconcepts to C++20. Clang 10 and GCC 10 give me the same unexpected problem, so it's probably my fault.

I have a class template that supports two cases. It can either be created from a list of pin_out's, or from a list of port_out's.

```
template< typename T > concept pin_out = T::is_pin_out;

template< typename... Ts > concept pin_out_list = ( pin_out< Ts > && ... );

template< typename T > concept port_out = T::is_port_out;

template< typename... Ts >
   requires pin_out_list< Ts...> || ( port_out< Ts > && ... )
struct port;
```

When I write the specialization for a list of pins_out's, with the concepts TS I could write

```
template< pin_out_list... Ts > 
struct port< Ts... > {};
```

but now with C++20 the compilers complain that the specialization is not more constrained than the base. When I add a requires clause it does compile.

```
template< pin_out_list... Ts > 
   requires pin_out_list< Ts... >
struct port< Ts... > {};
```

And I can remove the pin_out_list... from the template header.

```
template< typename... Ts > 
   requires pin_out_list< Ts... >
struct port< Ts... > {};
```

Is the pin_out_list... in the specialization now silently ignored?

test it on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/pjWST2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many things that [P1141](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html) changed was what a variadic constraint actually means:

> In [temp.param]/11 we have:
>
> ```
> template <C2... T> struct s3; // associates C2<T...>
> ```
>
> This seems to be doing an unexpected thing, which is having the constraint apply to more than one type in a pack at a time.

And as a result of that paper, a variadic constraint like that now applies to every type in the back. That is, we now have (this is in [[temp.param]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#5) now):

```
template <C2... T> struct s3; // associates (C2<T> && ... )
```

---

As a result, this specialization:

```
template< pin_out_list... Ts > 
struct port< Ts... > {};
```

means:

```
template <typename... Ts> requires (pin_out_list<Ts> && ...)
struct port<Ts...>;
```

and not:

```
template <typename... Ts> requires pin_out_list<Ts...>
struct port<Ts...>;
```

You need the latter meaning (this is the constraint in the primary expression) so you need to write the latter syntax. The compiler wasn't silently ignoring your specialization.

Comment: I saw that in deleted answer. But I deleted the answer because I thought another change in the standard made the specialization not more constrained than the primary template. Why does the normal form of  `(pin_out_list<Ts> && ...)` and `pin_out_list <Ts...>` differ?

Comment: @Oliv fold-expressions are atomic - So `(pin_out_list<Ts> && ...)` normalizes to that specific expression, while `pin_out_list<Ts...>` normalizes to the expression in the concept definition, which would be a different expression. [Maybe this helps?](https://godbolt.org/z/akjfVR)

Comment: Thanks! Is P1141 comprehensive for the cha nges from TS to C++20, or is there any other document that summarizes the changes?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I don't think there's any one document. There are a lot of changes. [P1084](https://wg21.link/p1084) and [P1452](https://wg21.link/p1452) are big ones.

Comment: @Barry Thank you, that helped me. This is realy tricky.  So for constraint normalization folded logical expression are not equivalent to a sequence of non folded logical expression... [This third](https://godbolt.org/z/xPQb9J) case compiles, and this compilation is not a compiler bug !?

Comment: @Oliv That's fine. The normalized form of `AllA<T1, T2>` is the `true` on the line 1 twice - we see through concepts. So `AllA<T1, T2>` is the same as `A<T1> && A<T2>`